# Compound Selector with parent and the this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with scraping data and sometimes the data does not have a class to easily access. For these situations I wanted to get the parent using .parent() and then making a compound selector like so. This does not seem to work very well. Here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/oLx9pyzt/17/

```
$(element).click( function () {
    var parentClass = $(element).parent().attr("class");
    var compoundelement = $("." + parentClass + " > " + this);
});
```

Comment: PLEASE SHARE THE HTML

Comment: Where are `element` and `parentClass` coming from? We'll need a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 I clarified that by editing the post above and added the jsfiddle.

Comment: @brk I added the jsfiddle.

Comment: We don't care about the fiddle. Your [mcve] needs to exist in your question. If jsFiddle is sold, blocked, goes down, or goes away, then your question will lose all value to future visitors without a complete example.

Comment: @j08691 I will edit this when I am home to be more comprehensive and lest dependant on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found. I posted the code in case the jsfiddle expires. The trick is to use $(element)[0].tagName instead of this or element alone.

```
function getElementsParent(element) {
  $(element).click(function() {
      var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
      var tagName = $(element)[0].tagName;
      var compoundelement = $("." + parentClass + " > " + tagName);
      var backgroundcolor = compoundelement.css("background-color");

       if (backgroundcolor.trim() == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
            compoundelement.css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
        } else {
            compoundelement.css("background-color", "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
        }
    });
}
```